# How to get serverTime from webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to know if it is possible to get the serverTime (in a variable that can be used later on in javascript) with jquery ajax functions as $.get() or $.post().

The link of the webpafe is :http://zz1.beta.tribalwars.net/game.php?village=1466&screen=overview

I think that for get and post functions you need to use the url: "game.php" 
This is a printscreen of the webpage: 
http://prntscr.com/4npk47

I could do something like that :

```
var time=document.getElementById('serverTime');
```

but with this method, after a while, if the webpage is not reloaded, the time is desynchronized with about 1-2 seconds, and i need the exact time.

Answer (score 1):

```
var serverTime = time ; //this would come from the server obviously
var localTime = +Date.now();
var timeDiff = serverTime - localTime;

setInterval(function () {
    console.log(+Date.now() + timeDiff);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I have noticed that the difference between local time and serverTime is not constant. So i can't use it as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Node.js on the backend with socket.io, using websockets, and stream the real-time (see how I did that!?). Then your client side JS would connect to the websocket and just stream the time out from the server.

Comment: sounds promising but i don't know if i have access to the backend. if you could elaborate that...